# Default principal object cannot be set twice

Tags: c#

I am getting this error  `Default principal object cannot be set twice` in my project. I am new to .net. Please help

**CODE**

```
       Principal = PrincipalFactory.CreatePrincipal(ServiceManager.UserService.ModifyUserName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name), Constants.ApplicationName);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Principal);
        ServiceManager.UserService.UpdateUser(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

I am getting error in line `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Principal);`. Please help

**ERROR**
 Default principal object cannot be set twice . at line  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Principal);

Comment: Please share what error you're getting.

Comment: @HéctorÁlvarez I am getting error like Default principal object cannot be set twice .

Comment: follow http://the-tread-way.blogspot.com/2010/05/supporting-multiple-logins-in-windows.html

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi what is the issue in my code can you tell me